# Docker connect NodeJS container with Apache container in front end JS

Tags: node.js, docker, socket.io, docker-compose

I am building a chat application that i am implementing in Docker. I have a NodeJS container with socket.io and a container with apache server and website on it.

The thing is i need to connect to the website(with javascript) to the NodeJS server. I have looked at the Docker-compose docks and read about networking. The docs said that the address should be the name of the container. But when i try that i get the following error in my browser console:

`GET http://nodejs:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED`

The whole project works outside containers.The only thing that i cannot figure out is the connection between the NodeJs container and the Apache container.

code that throws the error:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//nodejs:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

My docker compose file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:

  apache:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    networks:
      default:
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
    container_name: apache

  nodejs:
    image: node:latest
    working_dir: /home/node/app
    networks:
      default:
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
    volumes:
      - './node_server/:/home/node/app'
    command: [npm, start]
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    container_name: nodejs

networks:
  default:
    driver: bridge
```

Can anyone explain me how to succesfully connect the apache container to the NodeJS container so it can serve the socket.io.js file?

I can give more of the source code if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `nodejs` service is exposing port 3001 not 3000. `3001:3000` is a port mapping which forwards :3001 to the :3000 container port. So you would need to point it to `nodejs:3001`.

However, I don't think that'll work since the `nodejs` hostname is not accessible by the browser. You need to point it to the host in which docker is running since you are exposing those ports there. If you are running this locally it might look like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

In other words, you are not connecting to the nodejs server from the apache service, you are accessing it externally through the browser.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. 
  `In other words, you are not connecting to the nodejs server from the apache service, you are accessing it externally through the browser.`
  Is what i overlooked.